# Changing Uilabel text style Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, uilabel

I search on google about how to change style of text in UILabel but I got nothing. My text is long and when I wrote a long text it displays " When will you ... for me? " but I want it displays " When will you go to market ... ".
How can I do? Thank you for your kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `lineBreakMode` property to your label to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`. It will take care of that.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's work with `setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail ` . ;)

Answer (score 3):

you can do this in two ways

*option -1*

programmatically

**Objective-C**

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

**Swift**

```
label.lineBreakMode =.byTruncatingTail
```

other types are

```
  // NSParagraphStyle
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NSLineBreakMode) {       /* What to do with long lines */
NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0,      /* Wrap at word boundaries, default */
NSLineBreakByCharWrapping,      /* Wrap at character boundaries */
NSLineBreakByClipping,      /* Simply clip */
NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead,    /* Truncate at head of line: "...wxyz" */
NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail,    /* Truncate at tail of line: "abcd..." */
NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle   /* Truncate middle of line:  "ab...yz" */
}
```

*option -2*

using storyboard attribute inspector

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your label in storyboard go to the property of label > Line Breaks choose Truncate Tail. If your adding it programmatically then add bellow code

```
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```